# Can't instantiate Path() class on Javafx 2.0

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm learning javafx.

I'm trying to make a path, but when i instantiate the class Path(), i receive the following message: *"java.nio.file.Path is abstract; cannot be instantiated"*

```
package mapas;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.sound.midi.Patch;

public class Mapas extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Group circles = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    circles.setEffect(new BoxBlur(10, 10, 3));
    primaryStage.show();


    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        Circle circle = new Circle(150, Color.web("white", 0.05));
        circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.web("white", 0.16));
        circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
        circles.getChildren().add(circle);
    }
    root.getChildren().add(circles);

    Path path = new Path(); // <-- error 
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you want to `import java.nio.file.Path` as opposed to `javafx.scene.shape.Path`?????